# Unable to make the ImageView of one item in ListView invisible

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a row for a ListView defined as :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menutext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:src="@drawable/lock"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

My adapter for the ListView is set in `onCreate()`

```
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.send_menu_row, R.id.menutext, items));
```

I have 5 rows with a text and image on each row. In `onResume()`, I want to make the first row's `ImageView` invisible.

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    LinearLayout linLayout = (LinearLayout) listView.getAdapter().getView(0, null, null);
    ImageView v = (ImageView) linLayout.getChildAt(1);
    v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

But it doesn't change the visibility. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably what is happening is that you are not doing that in the right method.

Try to switch the device orientation from horizontal to vertical (or vice-versa). This should trigger `onResume` method to be invoked and it **could** work.

Anyway, hiding an image **shouldn't be done that way**. Perhaps you should use an empty image or override the getView method (in the adapter).

**UPDATE - why do I say you shoudn't use this method to do that**

The thing is `adapter.getView` is used to get a view that will be drawn. The OS calls this method when he needs to draw that item on the screen.

This method could be overriden by the developer to draw custom/complex views but it should be used (as in, invoked) exclusively by the system.

For example, when we are talking about long lists, if you scroll, you'll have the `getView` method invoked and it will receive a view to be reused (which is a lot more efficient). This means that if you hard-core that the first view will be invisible, when you scroll and the first view is reused to display the 20th item (for example), now the 20th item would be invisible because probably you would just update the label and image source.

**Note:**

When I say first view, I'm referring to the view where the first item is initially drawn. Later, the view that was used to accommodate the first item is going to be reused to accommodate another item.

**What is happening:**

I think I got it now. What I believe to be happening is the following:

When the activity is initially drawn, you'll have the `getView` method invoked 5 times (one for each item that you are displaying). Each time the OS collects the view returned and adds it to the listview.

Latter, you'll call `getView` by yourself. As you pass no view to be reused, the method will create another view and return it. What is different this time? You are not adding this view to the listview. (Also, this isn't what you what to do.)

what you wanted to do is get the view that *was* used to draw the first item. But in this case you are just getting *another* view that could be used to draw the first item.

The solution is overriding `getView` or using a transparent image (easier).

Here's a link for the first result on google:
http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Comment: I tried changing the orientation... still doesn't become invisible. Are you sure about "hidding an image shouldn't be done that way"? I don't see why.

Comment: I don't see why you shouldn't use setVisibility.

Comment: Pedro, I totally understand why getView should be used. Thank you for your comprehensive explanation. But you also say "or using a transparent image" - the problem I'm seeing is that I'm not able to change anything in onResume(); why is this particular issue happening?

Comment: As I said in my answer, what you get from calling ``getView`` passing in null, isn't the view that is being drawn (and the one that you see in the device) but it is another view that could fulfill the very same job (but you aren't seeing it). If you tried to add this view to the listView I think you'd see what you want (but this wouldn't be your desired result!)

Answer (score 2):

How about override getView and then do setVisibility when you return the first row in getView()?

It's not a great idea to be modifying rows outside of the list adapter. Since everytime the user scrolls you will lose the changes.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround maybe ?

Try making a transparent image (png) and put that in as first item :-)

Comment: I think its cleaner then putting something in the `onResume()`, but that only my opinion :-)

Comment: In this case, you could just set the image to `null` (or from the XML, `@null`).

Comment: @Programmer XR, maybe `onCreate()` would be better. But also wondering if this might have anything to do with !!!

Comment: I tried the following: `v.setImageResource(R.drawable.transparent);`, but it doesn't work. Looks like nothing is being set in the onResume() method. I wasn't able to change the text of the TextView either :(

Comment: I think an transparent image placeholder will be the best solution here, Rajath.

Comment: @Programmer XR, that will be difficult since there is only one placeholder for all the rows (atleast in the xml).